# be going to vs simple present in a if clause

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between the following two sentences?

> If you use medical marijuana to alleviate chronic pain, you have to obtain a doctor’s endorsement.

VS

> If you are going to use medical marijuana to alleviate chronic pain, you will have to obtain a doctor's endorsement.

Comment: The first example is present tense expressing present time, The second uses the progressive aspect ("are going" to express future time.

Comment: So you mean the first one means that using medical marijuana to alleviate chronic pain is happening right now, and the person who uses it needs to obtain a doctor's endorsement?

Comment: There's no meaning difference between the two sentences; _will, going to_ and _have to_ all refer to the future, one way or another. Different people might use one or the other in a given circumstance, but there's no consistent difference.

Answer (score 0):

The first one uses the present tense to make a general statement - '*anyone* who uses... has to...'.

The second addresses the reader/hearer directly - ' if you (personally) intend to use marijuana...'

Comment: I disagree. I think either of them can be general or direct.

Comment: What different rule is happy to extend 'anyone who uses... ' but not 'anyone who intends to/is going to use...'?